# Laravel how to use if stament in controller

Tags: php, laravel, if-statement, controller

I have 2 functions(`index` and `dateRange`) .

In `index.blade.php` I want to use if statement to choose which function it will run.

But when I type :

```
index{ if($request['from'] != null ) { //run this}
```

but this time the `indexController` not runs

```
request()->ajax() this if statement }..
```

How can i handle it?

Here is my whole function:

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    if (!Gate::allows('follow_access')) {
        return abort(401);
    }
    if (request()->ajax()) {
        $query = Follow::query()->where('qr_approved', 1)->where('qr_non_approved', 0);
        $query->with("competitor_product");
        $query->with("product");
        $query->with("user");
        $template = 'actionsTemplate';
        if ($request['From'] != null || $request['To'] != null) {
            dd("try me");
        }
        if (request()->ajax()) {
            // NOT WORK
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: post ur controller code complete

Comment: Blade `if`s are `@if()...@endif`

Comment: Please don't post code in comments, edit your question and paste it there. Thx

Answer (score 0):

Here updated below code

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    if (!Gate::allows('follow_access')) {
       return abort(401);
    }
    if ($request->ajax()) {
       $query = Follow::query()->where('qr_approved', 1)->where('qr_non_approved', 0);
       $query->with("competitor_product");
       $query->with("product");
       $query->with("user");
       $template = 'actionsTemplate';
       if ($request['From'] != null || $request['To'] != null) {
           dd("try me");
       }
       if ($request->ajax()) {
        // NOT WORK
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: I have changed request()-.>ajax() to $request->ajax()